# what data type to use for storing different files in database

Tags: sql, database, file, postgresql, sqldatatypes

Im trying to make a database accept different files in a postgres database table. The files I want to support are of different mime-types. I want to support pdf, word, plain text, and power point. The problem is that i don't know what datatype to choose. The documentation to pgadmin (the tool im using) is very (let´s say) unsatisfactory. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer.  I thought you meant MS SQL at first.  (READ ADAM, READ!)

Comment: You'd have to use a [binary data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-binary.html), but I urge you to reconsider doing this. It's generally not a good idea to store files in a DB. Store a path to the file instead. Read this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB

Comment: NullUserException might be right, but I store binary files in the database all the time without problems. I think storing files in the database is a good idea if you really care about data integrity. If you just store the path to the file, there's nothing to prevent that file from getting deleted or renamed, and then your data is no longer consistent.

Comment: I should also add that I'm speaking from somewhat limited experience, and I'm in the minority with my opinion. Storing files in the database might be a problem if you have a sufficiently large amount of data. I just wanted to point out that there's more than one opinion out there on this.

Comment: @JasonSwett There are pros and cons with both approaches. Ultimately it's up to the OP to decide which one is best for them; I personally tend to err on the side of not using the DB.

Comment: @JasonSwett: In addition to files getting deleted, you have to maintain some kind of congruence between database permissions and filesystem permissions.

Comment: hm so i read that there are two schools of thought on this link NullUserException so therefore Jason 's answer. But to me it seems as if Jason wins the argument for me. Thank you both for your input anyway

Answer (score 5):

While you can store the file *contents* in the database, consider storing the file *path* instead and using the file system to store the file.

In the IT world "you can do anything with anything", but that doesn't mean you *should*.

In this case, you're trying to use a database as a file system, which it can do, but databases are not as efficient or practical as file systems for storing file contents (typically "large" data). It will:

- make your backups longer and larger
- slow your insert queries down (more I/O)
- make your log files larger (slower and fill more often)
- make accessing the files slower (query vs simple disk I/O)
- require you to go via the database to access the files (hassle, can't use browser etc)
- etc

Comment: well is there a good information source to read about how to to this. I have never done such a thing.

Comment: There are several downsides in storing file paths as well: you'll have to duplicate access privileges, you can't store your files in a transactional manner, you need to make sure your database doesn't reference non-existing files, you need to make sure your filesystem doesn't contain non-referenced files, you need two different backups, you can't access the file contents through SQL (a hassle because you need to change technologies). In a nutshell: there is no clear winner. Either solution can be right - it all depends on the requirements.

Comment: I would also like to paraphrase Chris Date: make design decisions based on *logical* considerations first, *practical* considerations second. There's no real difference between a string, a number, the contents of an RTE, a CSV file or an image. All can be stored in a database equally validly. If there were no performance issues to consider, storing images in the database would, I think, be an absolute no-brainer.

Comment: @JasonSwett IMHO, you would have to *have* no brain to store images in the database. There is a whole (good) industry and technology built around decentralizing content. Putting images in a database is the direct opposite of this. I wouldn't dream of doing it, and I have seen it fail badly when attempted. Like I said in my answer, you can do anything with anything, but that doesn't mean you *should*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Probably the biggest downside is the *size* of the data in the table, and the impact this has on creating massive backup files. I wouldn't dream of doing it (see my previous comment for more)

Comment: @Bohemian: won't the backup be more or less the same size? It's a small backup for the DB and then still a massive backup for the file system. Using WAL archiving you can do differential backups for the DB as well. The total amount of data to backup doesn't really change (the DB will have *some* overhead though - that's correct)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the bytes maybe slightly more, but full database backups should be done frequently (to create a recent restore point) it would make the database backups and big and slow. Also, a small backup restores faster in case of DR. The flip side is file system backups are comparatively simple and fast. Storing paths is the way to go - the database stores the (relative) path and you can then keep numerous copies of the corresponding content files on servers in each continent to drastically reduce webpage load times globally. Don't use the database as a file system!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525 For a certain size of blob data the database is actually faster than the filesystem. It's for SQL Server, but I wouldn't be surprised if other DBMS would show similar results.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`bytea`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) type in PostgreSQL.

Comment: how many bytes does the entry for such an datatype range? And is there a way to set a limit, cause there is only one alternative. Thats bytea, not varying bytea. If you would want to set a limit how would you do that?

Comment: @patriques: bytea is basically "varying" see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html And the limit is 1GB (see:http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F )